# Jeep patriot sport 4x4 RPM/"4X4!"

Tags: jeep, rpm, patriot

I have a jeep patriot sport 4x4. Recently my RPM has been going up between 2,000 and 3,000 when im only driving between 60mph to 80mph on the freeway.. Is this normal? I also work on the mountain, im driving 60 to 65mph my RPM is at 3,000.

Also when i start to drive my "4X4!" comes on.

PLEASE HELP.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Is this an automatic or standard transmission? If automatic, have you checked the fluid levels in the transmission?

Comment: I believe the patriot automatic is a CVT.

Comment: My patriot is automatic.

Comment: I had a my transmission oil changed less than 2 months ago, If that helps.

Comment: That CVT I think does not have a dipstick so you can not readily check it. Its not a very big deal but you will need to go buy a dipstick. If you are not so inclined you should take it back where they changed it and have them check it.  ( google "how to check cvt fluid level jeep patriot" ) if you want to get into it yourself.